# Is it possible to format DB content (as string) before comparison with where clause

Tags: c#, linq, formatting, where-clause

I'd like to be able to take a url-formatted string (e.g **united-kingdom**) and use it in a WHERE clause against a Country column that is not formatted in such a way (e.g. **United Kingdom**).

Ideally,  I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
db.Jobs
.Where(j => j.Country.MyStringFormattingExtension() == urlformattedstring);
```

I understand that this is a no go because EF would try and execute the projection on the SQL side. It gives me: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String MyStringFormattingExtension(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

It has been suggested that I return the query as an enumerable before applying the where clause, however I think that this would be pretty inefficient - returning all rows from the DB before filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a user defined function and import that into your database. Read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/10/08/edm-and-store-functions-exposed-in-linq.aspx) for more details

```
// In SQL
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ToFormattedString ...

// In C#
public static class EntityFunctions 
{ 
    [EdmFunction("dbo", "ToFormattedString")] 
    public static string ToFormattedString(this string input) 
    { 
        throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls not supported");  
    } 
}

var results = db.Jobs.Where(j => j.Country.ToFormattedString() == urlFormattedString);
```

Alternatively, you can create a view in your database that materializes the string the way you want it to be formatted then join it into your Linq query.

```
// In SQL
CREATE VIEW dbo.vFormattedJobs AS ...

// In C#
var results =
    (from j in db.vFormattedJobs
     where j.FormattedCountry == urlFormattedString
     select j);
```

Comment: I'm getting there. Because I'm using a regex in the function I decided to try using a CLR User Defined Function.  I'm kind of stuck on that, but thought it better posted as a separate question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15669956/1778169

Answer (score 1):

How about going the other way, and converting the URL-formatted string into the database format before using it in the query?

```
var dbFormattedString = urlformattedstring.ConvertToDbFormat();
var result = db.Jobs.Where(j => j.Country == dbFormattedString);
```

(`db.Jobs` is already an `IEnumerable`, so I suppose that the suggestion was to call `ToList()` on it - it would have worked, but indeed, it would have been very inefficient unless the table is very small.)

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Unfortunately I don't think we'd be able to do that. We're working with a legacy DB that's integrated with multiple sites.  I think the StringFormattingExtension() is one-way. For example, we have some values like "Virgin Islands (UK)" that appear as "virgin-islands-uk". There's no way of knowing when the parenthesis have been stripped.