# How to register CLR User Defined Function for use in linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008-r2, clr

Using SQL Server 2008 I'd like to run a regex on a DB value before comparing it.

I'm looking into CLR User-Defined Functions (I investigated EDM Functions but I got the impression that UDFs were more appropriate with a regex - please correct me if I'm wrong).

Ideally I'd like to make a linq call like this:

```
var results= db.Items.Where(i => i.CustomFormatFunction() == xyz);
```

So far I have this c# code:

```
public static partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString CustomFormatFunction(string str)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(str), @"\s+", "-"), "[^a-zA-Z0-9/-]+", "").ToLower();
    }
}
```

What further steps are required in order for me to be able to use it in  a linq query?

Comment: by 'register' do you mean extension methods?

Comment: sorry I realised that wasn't clear. I edited it to: What further steps are required in order for me to be able to use it in a linq query?

Comment: any way that would allow me to call it in this fashion would be acceptable: db.Items.Where(i => i.CustomFormatFunction() == xyz);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually coded up this exact function some time ago. Mine's a bit more general purpose, but it looks like this:

```
[SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read, IsDeterministic = true)]
public static string Replace(string input, string pattern, string replacement, int options)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, (RegexOptions)options);
}
```

You then have to register it in SQL with

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [MyAssembly] 
FROM 'C:\Path\To\Assembly\MyAssembly.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Replace](@input [nvarchar](4000), @pattern [nvarchar](4000),  @replacement [nvarchar](4000), @options [int] = 0)
   RETURNS [nvarchar](4000) NULL
   WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
   AS EXTERNAL NAME [MyAssembly].[MyNamespace.UserDefinedFunctions].[Replace]
GO
```

That will create your CLR-UDF in SQL. I've never tried linking *back* to a linq query, but I assume it would work like any other EDM function.

```
[EdmFunction("dbo", "Replace")] 
public static string Replace(Replace input, pattern, replace, int flags) 
{ 
    throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls not supported"); 
}
```

You *might* even be able to put `SqlFunction` and `EdmFunction` attributes on the same method, but I don't recommend it (it also seems like pushing the limit of circularity). I prefer to keep my CLR-UDF functions in a completely separate assembly, since they change very infrequently and my assemblies which consume the data are very dynamic.

Comment: Hi again, and thanks for the answer. So should I be investigating how to put the 2 x Replace functions (SqlFunction and EdmFunction) into a separate assembly from the rest of the code? Or would they conflict and therefore need to be put in 2 separate assemblies?

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox I recommend creating an assembly exclusively for `SqlFunction` methods. The `EdmFunction` can remain with in the same assembly as your `EdmModel`. You won't need to reference the `SqlFunction` assembly at all.

Comment: We have it sorted... thanks ever so much for your persistent help on this one